# Ayuda con las comas en esta frase (coma antes de y / después de locución adverbial)

Tags: puntuación

Tengo dudas sobre cómo puntuar la siguiente frase:

> A pesar de eso parecen ser personas confiables y poco a poco comienzan a abrirse un poco más.

Específicamente, me pregunto si debe ir coma después de la locución adverbial "a pesar de eso", o antes de "y", o si deben ir ambas comas o sólo una de las dos.

Por ejemplo:

> A pesar de eso, parecen ser personas confiables y poco a poco comienzan a abrirse un poco más.

Poner sólo la coma después de "a pesar de eso" no me suena del todo correcto, porque pareciera significar que "a pesar de eso" modifica las dos partes de la oración: "A pesar de eso, parecen ser personas confiables" y "A pesar de eso, poco a poco comienzan a abrirse un poco más" (en este caso sólo la primera oración es cierta).

Pero si pongo una coma antes de la "y" para delimitar que "a pesar de eso" sólo aplica a lo anterior a esta coma, estaría colocando coma antes de la conjunción "y", lo cual creo que no está permitido (¿tal vez punto y coma?).

Además dudo si separar el "poco a poco" con comas:

> ... confiables y, poco a poco, comienzan a...
>   ... confiables, y poco a poco, comienzan a...
>   ... confiables, y poco a poco comienzan a...

Answer (score 5):

La entrada sobre el [uso de la coma en el Diccionario Panhispánico de Dudas](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/?key=coma) puede ayudarte. Particularmente, creo que estos puntos son pertinentes para tu pregunta:

> **1.1** Deben utilizarse dos comas, una delante del comienzo del inciso y otra al final [...] en aposiciones explicativas [...] o cuaqluier otra clase de comentario, explicación o precisión.
>
> **1.2.11** Se escribe coma detrás de determinados enlaces como *esto es, es decir, a saber, pues bien, ahora bien, en primer lugar, por un/otro lado, por una/otra parte, en fin, por último, además, con todo, en tal caso, sin embargo, no obstante, por el contrario, en cambio* y otros similares, así como detrás de muchos adverbios o locuciones adverbiales que modifican a toda la oración y no solo a uno de sus elementos. [Por ejemplo:] Por lo tanto, los que no tengan invitación no podrán entrar al recinto.

Debes poner coma después de `A pesar de eso` porque es una locución adverbial que modifica todo el sentido de la oración. Piénsalo de esta manera: *sin que lo expresado anteriormente sirva de impedimento*, parecen ser personas confiables y comienzan a abrirse un poco más.

Puedes poner comas al rededor de `poco a poco` porque se trata de una aposición explicativa que no guarda relación sintáctica alguna con la oración principal  (particularmente, una locución adverbial que nos indica cómo [ellos] comienzan a abrirse). Sabemos que no guarda relación sintáctica con la oración principal porque puedes extraer `poco a poco` y la oración sigue siendo coherente:

- Parecen ser personas confiables y, **poco a poco**, comienzan a abrirse un poco más.
- Parecen ser personas confiables y comienzan a abrirse un poco más.

Retomando lo mencionado, sugiero que la mejor manera de escribir tu enunciado es esta:

> A pesar de eso, parecen ser personas confiables y, poco a poco, comienzan a abrirse un poco más.